# Mathematica code to draw a graph of this differential equation?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Does anyone know the Mathematica code that will trace the graph below?

Here is the equation for the graph, a second order linear differential equation with constant coefficients:

[image]

Here is the graph traced by this equation:

[image]

Quote from the book "Times Series Analysis and Forecasting By Example":

> ... where δ(t ) is an impulse (delta) function that, like a pea shot, at
>   time t = 0 forces the pendulum away from its equilibrium and a is the
>   size of the impact by the pea. It is easy to imagine that the curve
>   traced by this second order differential equation is a damped
>   sinusoidal function of time although, if the friction or viscosity is
>   sufficiently large, the (overdamped) pendulum may gradually come to
>   rest following an exponential curve without ever crossing the
>   centerline.

Comment: Come on, now...[what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @Jack Maney I can't get this to work in Mathematica. I'd like an example of how to convert generic equations such as this into a form I can play around with in Mathematica. How do you specify an impulse function in Mathematica?

Comment: You have over 3600 reputation. You should know enough about Stack Overflow by now to know that questions logically equivalent to "gimmeh teh codez, plz?" with no indication that the OP has put in any effort generally won't fly here.

Comment: @Jack Maney I know a lot about C#, but not much about Mathematica. I didn't even know where to start. Your comment is a little harsh, perhaps?

Comment: @Gravitas, Perhaps this then: http://infinite-josiah.blogspot.com/2012/12/why-you-should-try.html

Comment: Related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17410/193

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
eq = m z''[t] + c z'[t] + k z[t] == a DiracDelta[t];
parms = {m -> 1, c -> .1, k -> 1, a -> 1};
sol = First@DSolve[{eq /. parms, z[0] == 1, z'[0] == 0}, z[t], t];
Plot[z[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 70}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{z[t], None}, {Row[{t, " (sec)"}], eq}}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice that, for zero initial conditions, another option is to use the Control system functions in Mathematica as follows

```
parms = {m -> 10, c -> 1.2, k -> 4.3, a -> 1};
tf = TransferFunctionModel[a/(m s^2 + c s + k) /. parms, s]
sol = OutputResponse[tf, DiracDelta[t], t];

Plot[sol, {t, 0, 60}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{z[t], None}, {Row[{t, " (sec)"}], eq}}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update**

Strictly speaking, the result of `DSolve` above is not what can be found by hand derivation of this problem. The correct solution should come out as follows

(see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17410/how-to-correctly-use-dsolve-when-the-force-is-an-impulse-dirac-delta-and-initi) also for reference)

The correct analytical solution is given by

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which I derived for this problem and similar cases in [here](http://12000.org/my_notes/dynamics_cheat_sheet/index.htm) (first chapter).

Using the above solution, the correct response will look like this:

```
parms = {m -> 1, c -> .1, k -> 1, a -> 1};
w = Sqrt[k/m];
z = c/(2 m w);
wd = w Sqrt[1 - z^2];
analytical = 
  Exp[-z w t] (u0 Cos[wd t] + (v0 + (u0 z w))/wd Sin[wd t] + 
     a/(m wd) Sin[wd t]);
analytical /. parms /. {u0 -> 1, v0 -> 0}

 (* E^(-0.05 t) (Cos[0.998749 t] + 1.05131 Sin[0.998749 t]) *)
```

Plotting it:

```
Plot[analytical /. parms /. {u0 -> 1, v0 -> 0}, {t, 0, 70}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{y[t], None}, {Row[{t, " (sec)"}], 
    "analytical solution"}}, GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you compare the above plot with the first one shown above using `DSolve` you can see the difference near `t=0`.